# Mahout Recommender: how to obtain new user recommendations?

Tags: servlets, command, mahout

Working with the Grouplens Mahout example, I know that to know the suggested movies for a partucular user, I can call:

```
http://localhost:8080/mahout-integration/RecommenderServlet?userID=2
```

But... which command/url should I call to obtain a list of suggested movies for a new user? Or, also: if a known user has new movies to rate, I DON'T WANT to reload all the ratings.dat with the new movies scored by the user. Is there a command to use with RecommenderServlet that permits to know the new user's raccomandations "on the fly", so without edit and then reload the ratings.dat?

For example, if the userId=2 has two new ratings (4 and 5) for two movies (with ID 1611 and 2345), something as:

```
http://192.168.1.3:8080/mahout-integration/RecommenderServlet?userID=2&newMovies=1611,2345&newRatings=4,5
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,
Geltry

Comment: It isn't really possible in Mahout. It updates only on reload. As Astatic says, the place where I really properly redesigned all this is Myrrix (http://myrrix.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [***Myrrix***](http://myrrix.com), which is in some ways the evolution of the taste (aka recommendations) portion of Mahout.

The [***REST API***](http://myrrix.com/rest-api) states the kind of operations you can do with the serving layer component of Myrrix, which includes setting new preferences for users which get folded into the model and made available for use without having to reload the entire model (although eventually you should refresh the model).

I'm not saying what you want is not possible with Mahout, but it's just not as easy and convenient.

Comment: Thank you Astatis. But, is it possible to call in some way the ingest method via http (for example: http://localhost:8080/ingest/1/123/1 means that user 1 rates 1 star for movie 123). If not, how can I do via java code? (however... great answer!!! :-)

Comment: I think Sean worded it quite well when he says that GET operations are supposed to be idempotent with no side effects.